# What is the difference between the many OpenSUSE flavors?

Tags: linux, opensuse

**Problem**

Hi. I'm from Debian Land.

I've used OpenSUSE before, but never on my own systems. I'm now attempting to understand it better as we have an application in development which will run on OpenSUSE.

OpenSUSE has a 'Tumbleweed', 'Factory', and a 'Leap'.

There is very little *clear and concise* information on the official OpenSUSE website describing the differences between these. The information is jumbled, mixed, poorly written and frustrating. (The OpenSUSE Wikipedia article appears outdated as well.)

**Question**

What is the difference between these various OpenSUSE releases/flavors?

Comment: install a container in top of Debian with OpenSUSE and be done with it...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ---> You could not answer the question with an actual answer but I admire your snark.

Comment: We have had SuSE and OpenSUSE here. Remarkably similar to RedHat/CentOS. SuSE is the paid version, and you guess it OpenSUSE is the free version. I am not joking. I know very soon I will be asked to install a RH application and I will do the same.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: And Tubmleweed/Factory/Leap...........?

Comment: I am not that experienced in SuSE. I migrated all of it to Debian a lot of moons ago. I do maintenance in scale, I do not intend to administer clusters of different OSes.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: If you migrated everything to Debian then you certainly know what you are doing. Smart move..........for this question here, I will wait for an answer from someone.

Comment: I do know my ways around SuSE or any RedHat, I just want to have a unique standard, a sole base image, and not combat in multiple fronts at the same time.

Comment: To be truthful, I sure know SuSE has been investing a lot in commoditisation of virtualization in the last version(s). Combating the prevalence of RedHat in the Enterprise,  mainly in Europe. Their integration products are an easy sell.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just quoting the [openSUSE wiki](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Factory) here:

> The Factory project is the rolling development codebase for openSUSE
>   Tumbleweed.
>
> There is a constant flow of packages going into Factory. There is no
>   freeze; therefore, the Factory repository is not guaranteed to be
>   fully stable and is not intended to be used by humans. The core system
>   packages receive automated testing via openQA.
>
> When automated testing is completed and the repo is in a consistent
>   state, the repo is synced to the download mirrors and published as
>   openSUSE Tumbleweed. That usually happens once or twice a week.
>
> Factory is mainly used as an internal term for openSUSE's distribution
>   developers, and the target project for all contributions to openSUSE's
>   main codebase.
>
> Power users, developers, and openSUSE contributors are recommended to
>   use the Tumbleweed rolling release.
>
> Conservative users who just need a working system ("if it ain't broke,
>   don't fix it") are advised to stay with the current stable release.

Leap is the current stable release.

Clear and concise enough for me.

Comment: Just a note, from my perspective, the clarity could possibly use some work.  As of now, https://www.opensuse.org/ refers to Tumbleweed as "Stabilized!" and "Tested!" and to Leap as merely the "most complete" "regular-release".  To an outsider, this could seem to be the opposite of what the wiki says.

Comment: [Tumbleweed is updated once Factory's bleeding edge software has been integrated, stabilized and tested.](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Tumbleweed)(probably the source of the slogan)

Comment: I do get that from the wiki, but coming from Debian land myself, I just looked at the https://opensuse.org site ... and found that clicking for more information on Tumbleweed tells us that it is a "stable platform", whereas clicking for more information on Leap does not mention the word "stable", but describes Leap as "stabilized", which described Tumbleweed on the previous page.  Room for more clarity there, I'd say.